# Bind dropdown list from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have been struggling to create a Dropdown list which will display Country names from database.
**The situation is:**
I have a Controller "AdvertisementController", a model"AdvertisementModel" and a View "Create.cshtml".
On the view I need to create a dropdown list which will display country names from database.

I know the good thing will be to create a Viewmodel. But how shall I do that?
A bunch of code will be much appreciated. :)

I have the following code but it shows 'null reference' error.

Viewmodel:

```
 public class CommunicationViewModel
    {

        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class CreateAdModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ad type")]
        public string AdType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ad category")]
        public string AdCategory { get; set; }

        public CommunicationViewModel categories { get; set; }


    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = db.AddCategory.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Value = c.ID.ToString(),
                                                     Text = c.Name
                                                 }
                                                 );
        var model = new CommunicationViewModel { CategoryList = query.AsEnumerable() };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Razor:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.categories.CategoryID,Model.categories.CategoryList,"--Select one--")
```

Comment: Try and search for "mvc dropdownlist". Tons of question just like yours :)

Comment: Cheers Kasper for your brilliant idea..:). I did follow you and find some error. Guess I am doing some mistakes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you. Drop down for roles when adding users. very simple tutorial

http://rtur.net/blog/post/2009/06/03/Quick-and-dirty-role-management-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Comment: Download at the bottom of the page.